# Register one Service with multiple names for every Component of certain service by convention

Tags: c#, castle-windsor, ioc-container, castle

I use Castle-Windsor 3.1 and C# 4.0.

I register some components (views) by convention, like this

```
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn(typeof(ITabPageView<>))
                .WithServiceFromInterface(typeof(ITabPageView<>))
                .LifestyleTransient()
                .Configure(c => c.Properties(PropertyFilter.IgnoreAll))
```

This works as expected. What I now want is, register another component of one service-type for **every** `ITabPageView` component.
In concrete example (PRISM), I want to register a `IRegionManager` for every registered TabPage, with the name of that tab page. The region managers have to be created by one central region manager, already registered.
At the moment I do it like this:

```
            Classes.FromThisAssembly()
                .BasedOn(typeof(ITabPageView<>))
                .WithServices(typeof(IRegionManager))
                .Configure(c =>
                    {
                        c.UsingFactoryMethod(kernel => kernel.Resolve<IRegionManager>().CreateRegionManager())
                            .Named(c.Implementation.Name);
                    })
```

While this actually seems to work I wonder if there is a more elegant or robust way.

Thanx.

Comment: So why do you want a `IRegionManager` for each `ITabPageView`? How is it being used? Why wouldn't a single `IRegionManager` component work?

Comment: This is due to PRISM requires region names to be unique for a single region manager, so I thought I needed several instances,
but meanwhile I refactored my views, so this question is more kind of an academical interest.

Comment: Right. The short answer is, Windsor doesn't have an easy way to do it, because usually it's not the best way